# determining probability dist based on function calls

Tags: probability

If we have this matlab function:

```
function X = reject(N):
  for i = 1:N
    y = rand;
    while (true)
      if rand == y;
        X = y;
        break;
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Let's denote $T_1$ the random variable equal to the number of calls to the function $rand$ when running $reject(1)$. What is the distribution of $T_1$ and its expectation?

$rand$ returns a random scalar drawn from the uniform distribution in the interval $(0,1)$.

Also, if $S_{N>0}$ a random variable equal to the number of calls to the function
$rand$ when executing $reject(N)$. What is the expectation of $S_{N>0}$ ?

Comment: I suggest showing what inside rand is.

Comment: Is the domain of rand a subset of the real numbers or are they some sort of machine numbers? Because if it's not a discrete set the probability of picking two real numbers with a uniform distribution and have them be the same is constantly zero.

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/rand.html

Comment: But my question doesn't concern anything about what rand does, we're just talking about the number of calls, and that it generates some number, it is from a uniform distribution.

Comment: I think my question is seriously misunderstood, there is no need to know anything about the behavior of $rand$, this should be I think a binomial distribution. All we know is that rand returns a random scalar drawn from the uniform distribution in the interval $(0,1)$.